# Pivot Chart - Using detail values for Value Set 1 and Grand Total Values for Value Set 2

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table

I currently have a dataset that consists of 30,000 records. Each record contains the **Action Performed**, **Week**, **Person who Completed the Work**, **QC Flag**. So in a day we might have 8 people work 3 tasks for a total of 700 work items. We randomly sample 40 of those cases and they fail 3 of those 40 collectively.

I would like a pivot chart that has a stacked column showing the portion of the total work allotted to each task. <---- Easy and completed

Then on the secondary axis I want to show the fail rate... not as a percentage of the total but as a percentage of those qc.

So, I can get the pivot data to say:

Week [1]...QC Fail [3]...QC Pass [37]...QC Blank [660]

...at the Task level. But the output shows the fail rate per task and I do not want that. I want task delineated by volume and the fail rate of the total population.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of meddling and trial and error I figured out a solution. It's a dirty workaround but it gets the job done. I created one flag field per task as calculated fields in my data. In addition I created flag fields for all items that failed QC. Then my pivot used Week as Row and nothing but values as columns. My values were then count of each task type, sum of my fail flag field, count of QC items. I then displayed the tasks as a stacked column and the fails and total QC as a stacked 100% line and I changed the scale to only display up to 15% and I deleted the total QC line. I will now have to add a flag field for each new task added. Dirty... but after 7 hours I'm done.